# iOS AppDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotification not triggered with silient push on cellular network in background

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application that receives silent push notifications from Firebase and triggers upload by URLSession with background configuration.
Everything works well on WiFi network, application woke up in the background, didReceiveRemoteNotification triggered and upload request is preparing.
But after disabling WiFi, on the cellular network it's not happened and continues immediately after WiFi-enabled and connected...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have turn on background refresh for cellular data too. You can turn on from following:

Settings > General > Background App Refresh:
Off
Wi-Fi
Wi-Fi & Cellular Data

Comment: yes, thanks, of course it's turned on, i have tested it on several devices, but with no success...